# Toggle filterable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of links with data attributes to **filter divs**. The filtering gets enabled on click and then disabled **(back to show all divs)** when clicked again. The filtering works fine but if a link is clicked (enabled) and then another one is clicked, I want the next corresponding divs to be shown, and **prevent all divs** to be shown until the link is clicked once again.
How can I achieve this?

```
var enabled = false;

$('.show-div').click(function(e) {

   enabled = !enabled;

   if(enabled) {
      $('.result-div').hide();
      $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).show();
   }else {
      $('.result-div').show();
   }   

});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="show-div" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="4">Div 4</a>

<div id="div1" class="result-div">Result 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="result-div">Result 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="result-div">Result 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="result-div">Result 4</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdornell/vkjLrbxc/1/)

Comment: if you post your html it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only show the same element clicked again.so save  `target` value then match with `current` and `prev` Clicked element `target` value

**Updated**  with toggle

```js
$(function() {
  var target;

  $('.show-div').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();;

    if (target != $(this).attr('data-target')) {
      $('.result-div').hide();
      $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).show();
      target = $(this).attr('data-target')

    } else {
      $('.result-div').show();
      target ='';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show-div" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="4">Div 4</a>


<div id="div1" class="result-div">Result 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="result-div">Result 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="result-div">Result 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="result-div">Result 4</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but with that solution the toggle only trigger once per link. The toggle should execute on every click.

Comment: once per means which one?

Comment: When I click a link, the toggle works once for that particular link. I want the toggle to work infinite number of times on a particular link.

Comment: Check my updated answer .simply reset the `target ` in else

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works like I wanted. I've updated the fiddle with css animations, but if I've clicked on a link to filter and then click again to show all divs, the animation is not working on the div which is currently visible. How can I make the animation execute on all divs every time a link is clicked? [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdornell/vkjLrbxc/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/vkjLrbxc/3/

```js
$(function() {
 var prevClick = 0;
  $('.show-div').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
     if(parseInt($(this).attr('data-target')) !== parseInt(prevClick)) {
        $('.result-div').hide();
       $('#div' + parseInt($(this).attr('data-target'))).show();
        prevClick = parseInt($(this).attr('data-target'));
     }else {
        prevClick = 0;
        $('.result-div').show();
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show-div" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="4">Div 4</a>


<div id="div1" class="result-div">Result 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="result-div">Result 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="result-div">Result 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="result-div">Result 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `enabled`  value to **data-target**

```js
var enabled = false;

$('.show-div').click(function(e) {
   if(enabled== $(this).attr('data-target')) {
$('.result-div').show(); 
  }else {
  $('.result-div').hide();
  $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).show();
  enabled = $(this).attr('data-target');
   }   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show-div" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
<a class="show-div" data-target="4">Div 4</a>


<div id="div1" class="result-div">Result 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="result-div">Result 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="result-div">Result 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="result-div">Result 4</div>
```